# Best way to iterate through the following awk command

Tags: bash, awk

I have the following awk statement

```
awk '/^string$/{i=1;next} i && i++ <= 2' file
```

This will search for string and then print 2 lines down.

So as an example

```
$ cat file
string
aaa
bbb
ccc

$ awk '/^string$/{i=1;next} i && i++ <= 2' file
$ bbb
```

What I want to do is change the 2 into a counter, so that I can iterate 10 lines down each time. For example

```
for i in {1..5}
do
   awk '/^111$/{i=1;next} i && i++ <= $i' file
done
```

That of course does not work and I am not sure if this is even possible  as the command is encapsulated in the loop.

For reference, what I want to do is check within a config file (file.cfg) for a value [header] and see if a variable is enabled (variable = enabled)

For example

```
cat file.cfg
[header]
# nothing
variable = enabled
```

I guess the key attributes are that [header] will be on an undetermined line (it could be line 1 it could be line 122)

And variable is not always going to be the second line after [header], some people might put it 7 places down, others 2 places down.

Hope that makes sense and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In the shell you can concatenate strings if they are juxtaposed with no intervening spaces, eg:

```
echo 'abc$def'"and so on"
abc$defand so on
```

So in your example simply exit the (') string and start a (") string so your
`$i` can be interpolated by the shell:

```
awk '/^111$/{i=1;next} i && i++ <= '"$i" file
```

Also, if your `[header]` strings are easily distinguishable from the data
lines, you can just use awk's ability to run a command when between two
lines. Eg:

```
seq 10 | awk '/6/,/9/{print}'
```

will print lines 6 to 9. So instead of doing your own counting, and
assuming `[header1]` is a typical header syntax (so you need to escape the `[`), you could use something like

```
awk '/^\[header1]/,/^\[header2]/ { print }'
```

Answer (score 1):

If your config file is build up using `[header]` lines followed by `variable=value` lines you can use the following command to get all the values from a specific section:

```
sed -n '/^\[header\]/,/^\[/p' /path/to/file.cfg|grep -vE '?\s?[;#]'
```

The `sed` part will filter all the lines from the `[header]` up to (and including) the next line starting with a `[` character. The `grep` command will filter out lines which have a `;` or `#` as starting character.

Instead of sed you might use `awk`. Based on an earlier answer on question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17988756/how-to-select-lines-between-two-marker-patterns-which-may-occur-multiple-times-w:

```
awk '/\[header\]/{print; flag=1; next}/\[/{flag=0}flag' file.cfg
```

You can append the `grep` command as above if you want to filter out commented lines.